# Loop through array that might be multi dimensional

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I might have the following `array()`

```
Array([
    0
]=>Array([
    part_id
]=>6[
    part_user_id
]=>2[
    part_department
]=>3[
    part_category
]=>1[
    part_subcategory
]=>1[
    part_name
]=>SparePart[
    part_qty
]=>1[
    part_condition
]=>New[
    part_description
]=>Thisisadescription[
    part_image
]=>images/parts/default.jpg)[
    1
]=>Array([
    part_id
]=>7[
    part_user_id
]=>2[
    part_department
]=>3[
    part_category
]=>1[
    part_subcategory
]=>1[
    part_name
]=>SparePart[
    part_qty
]=>1[
    part_condition
]=>New[
    part_description
]=>Thisisadescription[
    part_image
]=>images/parts/default.jpg))
```

From data I have got from MYSQL, the same query might also return more than one row so I could also receive this `array()`

```
Array([
    part_id
]=>7[
    part_user_id
]=>2[
    part_department
]=>3[
    part_category
]=>1[
    part_subcategory
]=>1[
    part_name
]=>SparePart[
    part_qty
]=>1[
    part_condition
]=>New[
    part_description
]=>Thisisadescription[
    part_image
]=>images/parts/default.jpg)
```

I am looping through to output in my HTML

```
foreach($myResults as $row => $value){

}
```

This loop will work fine when I receive more than 1 row from the DB. If I receive 1 row I obviously run into problem.

What is the best way for me to check what I have received in order to loop or simply output dependent on my result?

Comment: Are you using two different functions for retrieving from the DB? It should come back as an array even if there is only one row.

Comment: It would help if you showed how `$myResults` was created.

Comment: I am looping through the rows and adding the values to an array. It's a CRUD Class that I am using

Comment: So even if there is only 1 row still add it to an array. Then your foreach loop will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check if value is an array.
If yes loop it too.

```
if (is_array($value)) foreach ($value as $value2) {}
```

Comment: They are both arrays so this will be true no matter what